# Convention of where to store files on a user's machine

Tags: python, storing-data

I'm working on a Python package which will need a database, and somewhere store it on a user's machine. My problem is that I'm not quite sure where to put it. I have seen some projects such as matplotlib and NLTK storing their data in a dot directory in `$HOME`, but I have also noticed that some people get quite irritated of developers messing up their home directory. Is placing data here still the convention I should follow, or are their other places where they might belong?

Comment: @Vor I'm on OS X, but since this is for a package to be openly distributed on pip, I am hoping for a relatively OS dependent solution.

Comment: This might be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com - this is cross-OS, and neither implementation- nor Python-specific.

Comment: I think `$HOME` is the only portable place you can put files. Otherwise you going to have use OS specific methods of determining other places to put the files. You could also potentially use something like wxPython which has OS independent interfaces for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to store data in:

```
import os
os.environ['HOME']
```

Any other path would generally have to be coded to be OS specific, such as program files in windows.

Comment: Under linux it is common to store user specific data in a hidden directory in that users home directory - and not just in their home directory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: Also look at http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#HOMEUSERHOMEDIRECTORIES